# Como destacar uma palavra usando REGEX

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Preciso colorir no RichTextBox um texto antes de uma string Por exemplo:

"Destacar: destaque normal"

Comment: O texto após o `:` deve ser interpretado como um regex ou como um literal? Por exemplo, se o texto tiver um `?` ele deve dar match com uma interrogação (literal) ou deve ser interpretado como um operador optativo do pattern precedente (regex)?

Comment: Só o `:` que limita o texto antes, depois dele qualquer texto pode ser literal.

Answer (score 5):

Veja se isso pode te ajudar

```
private void ColourRrbText(RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        Regex regExp = new Regex("^([^:]*)");

        foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(rtb.Text))
        {
            rtb.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
            rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eu precisava fazer isso enquanto a pessoa digita, e no RichTextBox terá varias linhas e não só uma linha. Tem como fazer isso enquanto a pessoa digita ou quando apaga o limitador que é o `:`?

Comment: @SérgioHenrique Seria bom você ter dito isso na pergunta